# PHP str_replace <tag>Stuff - Things</tag> into <a href="stuff">Stuff<a href="things">Things?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, str-replace

In **$variable** I have html code which reads like:`

```
<tag>Lots of Text Here - More Phrases Here</tag>.
```

I'd like to be able to **str_replace** the string in between the 2 tags

```
<tag> string </tag>
```

I want the new code to read:

```
<tag><a href="Lots">Lots</a> <a href="of">of</a>
<a href="text">Text</a> <a href="here">Here</a> - 
<a href="@morephraseshere">@MorePhrasesHere</a></tag>
```

I know this might be a lot to str_replace all at once, but if you can at least get either the "Lots of Text Here" to become links, or if you can get the @MorePhrasesHere to become a link it would be amazing.

Or the closest you can get to a full solution would be fantastic as well.

The string of text in $variable changes for each entry. A **preg_match or str_explode** solution for $variable would be amazing as well if you can't do it in str_replace.

Thank you!

**Edit:** The objective is to turn every word in the first string into a #hashtag, and every word in the second string into a @username. The server knows how to return valid responses for both types of links.

Comment: does it every time begin from <tag> and have </tag> at the end?

Comment: Yes the 2 tags will be consistent, the text inside will always change. There will always be a " - " in between the two strings: "<tag>string - string2</tag>

Comment: You can't use `str_replace` you don't know what will be inside. You could use `preg_replace` or `preg_match`. If you use `preg_match` you'll have to construct the link with the found values after. In your example how did `text` and `here` get linked?

Comment: Hi chris, thanks for coming back. I figured I could str_replace the blank spaces with str_replace (' ',' <a href="$1">$1', $var  but I'm realizing how complicated this is to do. I'll look into preg for it if you think that is better. Thanks again chris you were so helpful last time.

Comment: Let's state the question. There is a string  <tag>blabla bla2 - lololo lo2</tag>. You want take 1st part before minus and every word wrap into <a> tag. And full 2nd part (after minus) wrap in common <a> tag. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, the objective is to turn every word in the first string into a #hashtag, and every word in the second string into a @username. The server knows how to return valid responses for both types of links

Comment: OK. I think now you will get many answers :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do this with `preg_match`, http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php. The `.` means any character, the `*` is a quantifer meaning 0 or more occurrences of the previous character. Since it is `.` we are allowing everything. The `?` de-greedifys so it is looking for the first occurrence of `-` then we pull everything else again until `</tag>`.

```
<?php
preg_match('~<tag>(.*?)-(.*?)</tag>~', '<tag>Lots of Text Here - More Phrases Here</tag>', $found);
echo '<a href="#' . urlencode(trim($found[1])) . '">' . trim($found[1]) . '</a>' . "\n";
echo '<a href="@' . urlencode(trim($found[2])) . '">' . trim($found[2]) . '">' . '</a>' . "\n";
?>
```

Output:

```
<a href="#Lots+of+Text+Here">Lots of Text Here</a>
<a href="@More+Phrases+Here">More Phrases Here"></a>
```

You should start learning the metacharacters and quantifiers. This will help you write your own regexs in the future. You should navigate around this site; it is a bit long but has a lot of information too, http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html

Comment: Yes I will try to learn more about proper regex especially considering how much I've been writing in it lately and how little I know. Thank you so much for the solution and the link. I will test your code out soon and will read up more. Thanks again Chris!

Answer (score 0):

Take this code. There is nothing to explain

```
$title = '<tag>Lots of Text Here - More Phrases Here</tag>';

preg_match('/<tag>\s*(.+)\s+-\s+(.+)\s*<\/tag>/', $title, $matches);
$res = '<tag>';
$words = explode(' ', $matches[1]);
foreach ($words as $word) 
    $res .= '<a href="#'.$word.'">'.$word.'</a> ';
    $after = str_replace(' ','', $matches[2]);
$res .= '<a href="@'.$after.'">@'.$after.'</a></tag>';
echo $res;
```

Comment: Yes the problem is that you're replacing the string "lots of text here - more phrases here" but i need text replaced inside of 2 variables.  It is "$title = $entry->title;" so the variable would be $title. Chris did the same thing, he's preg_matching the string but not the variable. I appreciate you trying though, and the code actually preg_matched the string and echoed successfully.

Comment: I specialy did not use regulars because you said that don't know them. Using makes code easyy